# Critical points of $f(x,y)=\sin(x)+\sin(y)-\sin(x+y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

Domain: $0 \le x<\pi$ and $0 \le y<\pi$

After setting the gradient of $f(x,y)$ equal to zero, I obtained the following system:

$\cos(x)=\cos(x+y),$  $\cos(y)=\cos(x+y)$

I am not sure how to solve this system but what I tried was:

On the given domain, the first equation implies $x=x $ and $y=0$.

The second equation implies $y=y $ and $x=0$ so the system is consistent when $(x,y)=(0,0)$?

And thus $(0,0)$ is the only critical point in the given domain?

Comment: sorry I have just fixed it

Comment: @Moo Needlessly complicated and generally unhelpful.

Comment: @Moo so (0,0) is the only solution for the given domain?

Comment: @Moo I would say that based on Andy6978's response, your comment failed to help him figure out the solution set. The fact that you deleted it further supports it, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both equations hold simultaneously, we'll have $\cos(x)=\cos(y)$. Since the cosine is injective in $[0,\pi]$, this implies $x=y$.

Now, we need only solve $\cos(x)=\cos(2x)$. Of course, $x=0$ is a solution, but are there more?
The double angle formula yields $\cos(2x)=2\cos(x)^2-1$, so we need to solve

$$2\cos(x)^2-\cos(x)-1=0$$

Letting $t=\cos(x)$, we have a quadratic equation $2t^2-t-1=0$. The solutions are

$$t=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+8}}{4}=\frac{1\pm3}{4}=1\,\text{ or }\, -\frac{1}{2}$$

The solution $t=1$ corresponds to $x=y=0$, while the solution $t=-\frac12$
 corresponds to $x=y=\frac{2\pi}3$, which is the critical point you missed.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the gradient to zero yields
$$
\begin{cases}
\cos x - \cos(x+y)=0 \\[6px]
\cos y - \cos(x+y)=0
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore $\cos x=\cos y$. If we are interested in the whole plane, this means
$$
y=x+2k\pi
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
y=-x+2k\pi
$$
With the second set of solutions we get $x+y=2k\pi$, so $\cos(x+y)=1$ and we obtain $\cos x=1$, so 
$$
x=2a\pi \qquad y=2b\pi
$$
for arbitrary integers $a$ and $b$.

With the first set of solutions we get $x+y=2x+2k\pi$, so $\cos(x+y)=\cos x$ becomes
$$
\cos 2x=\cos x
$$
This reduces to $2x=x+2h\pi$ or $2x=-x+2h\pi$. In the first case we get solutions we have already found, so it remains to consider $3x=2h\pi$.

This gives
$$
x=\frac{2h\pi}{3}\qquad y=\frac{2h\pi}{3}+2k\pi \tag{*}
$$
again for arbitrary integers $h$ and $k$.

The only solutions that satisfy $0\le x<\pi$ and $0\le y<\pi$ are
$$
\begin{cases}
x=0\\[6px]
y=0
\end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{cases}
x=\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\\[6px]
y=\dfrac{2\pi}{3}
\end{cases}
$$

---

If you want the solutions in (*) to be “symmetric” in $x$ and $y$, you can write them in the forms
$$
\begin{cases}
x=\dfrac{2\pi}{3}+2a\pi \\[6px]
y=\dfrac{2\pi}{3}+2b\pi
\end{cases}
\quad
\begin{cases}
x=\dfrac{4\pi}{3}+2a\pi \\[6px]
y=\dfrac{4\pi}{3}+2b\pi
\end{cases}
$$